# kubernetes : How to deattach from an attached pod

Tags: kubernetes, stdin

I have a running pod and I use `kubectl attach -ti mypod` to give him input.

But then, I would like to "deattach" from my pod and return back to my terminal without terminating my pod.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the kubernetes [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/docker-cli-to-kubectl/#docker-attach):

> To detach from the container, you can type the escape sequence Ctrl+P
> followed by Ctrl+Q.

---

Update:

Based on feedback from @Abdelghani:

> For the record, this does not work if tty is set to false in the
> container. I didnt find another way to detach other than killing the
> pod/container.

Comment: For the record, this does not work if tty is set to false in the container. I didnt find another way to detach other than killing the pod/container

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Abdelghani, I have updated my answer to include the limitations.

Comment: I was not able to get ctrl-P + ctrl-Q to work for me, but an alternative solution for me was to start the deployment/pod with tty set to false but attach to the pod with the `-t` flag. In this way, i was able to use ctrl-c to detach myself from the pod without sending the ctrl-c signal to my application

Answer (score 4):

You can kill the `kubectl attach -it ..` process without killing the pod:

```
host$ kubectl attach -it podname
pod$ do something in pod
```

Open the other terminal and find your `kubectl attach` command and then kill it, something like:

```
host$ ps x | grep "kubectl attach"
> 1234 pts/22   Sl+    0:00 kubectl attach -it podname
host$ kill 1234
```